# Creating my own probability map based on the occupancyGrid map?

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would like to navigate the turtlebot in a map that i have creating using gmapping. But i would like to set the goal positions based on my own logical probability map which gives me the next goal the robot has to move to. Could someone throw some light on how to create my own map, which would be corresponding to the occupancygrid map that came out of gmapping.

I didn't find any tutorials on costmap_2d so is there anything that i am missing. Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
Karthik

Atleast if i know how to access the available OccupancyGrid map in ros, I could generate my own Matrix using OpenCV's Mat structure and define my goals. Let me know if this is a good procedure.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28726/creating-my-own-probability-map-based-on-the-occupancygrid-map?/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Changing the costmap will only change the path the robot takes to get to the goal. You should be able to track the probability map on your own and send the selected goal to move_base independent of costmap_2d.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-03-02**:
Thanks David, it may b a silly questions but could you tell me how to know the number of rows n columns of the available OccupancyGrid map once the map is built. So that i can create a matrix of same dimensions to assign my prob values.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-03-02**:
In a global costmap, it is the same as your map.